# Amazon AMI with Caffe

Tags: amazon-web-services, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, amazon-ami

I am looking for an Ubuntu AMI for AWS which has Caffe installed and works properly with GPU. There are some on caffe's Github [page](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Caffe-on-EC2-Ubuntu-14.04-Cuda-7) but they seem to be [not working](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-ec2-instance). Is there a recently tested AMI available now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this [AMI](http://cs231n.github.io/aws-tutorial/) offered by Stanford. Remember to choose the region as

> US West (N.California)

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Recently, I have found and used one AMI that contains basically everything you need to run Caffe. You might find it [here](https://github.com/bitfusionio/amis/tree/master/awsmrkt-bfboost-ubuntu14-cuda75-caffe)